# Does $A$ have any special status as an $\mathrm{End}(A)$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $\mathrm{End}(A)$ its endomorphism ring. Then to give an abelian group $B$ the structure of a (left) $\mathrm{End}(A)$ module, we provide a morphism $\mathrm{End}(A)\to\mathrm{End}(B)$. Obviously $\mathrm{id}:\mathrm{End}(A)\to\mathrm{End}(A)$ gives $A$ the structure of an $\mathrm{End}(A)$ module.

Q: Does $A$ have in general any special properties as an $\mathrm{End}(A)$ module? Obviously it's not e.g. the free $\mathrm{End}(A)$ module on a single generator or something (since that's $\mathrm{End}(A)$).

A related question is whether non-isomorphic abelian groups can have isomorphic endomorphism rings. I suspect they can (but I should definitely think about this question more), which rules out the possibility that $A$ can have any truly universal properties in the category of $\mathrm{End}(A)$ modules, since universal properties are unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: For torsion free abelian groups, an isomorphism of endomorphism rings implies an isomorphism of the groups: this is a theorem of Kaplanski and Baer. On the other hand, this is not true if you have torsion. You should look in Fuchs's book on abelian groups.

Comment: This is conceptually and, I think, also technically related to questions of "Tannakian reconstruction" especially in cases where there is a reasonable notion of dimension of objects.

Comment: One interesting result suggesting there may not be nice answer in general: "there are torsion-free groups A of arbitrarily large cardinality $\kappa$ such that—as
End$A$-modules—they cannot be generated by less than $\kappa$ elements". This an exercise on page 650 of Fuchs (2015).

Comment: Thanks for all of the useful comments, especially @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez. I will do some further reading on this topic. Your comments have aroused my interest.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Just to point out: the theorem of Kaplanski and Baer concerns torsion groups, not torsion free ones.